# Simple Question on Clicking Colliders in UI Layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a very simple question but I need to click the head of a 2D golf club in my game. It's a sprite with a 2D polygon collider on it and I just need it to only work when the collider is pressed. Do raycasts work wit this still?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried using a few codes but to no avail, I'm quite rusty at Unity.

[enter code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raFqv.png)

Here's the prop+[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hFpb.png)

Comment: "I've tried using a few codes[sic]" - Then show us your code.

Comment: "It's a sprite with a 2D polygon collider on it and I just need it to only work when the collider is pressed." - One of the few moments on StackOverflow where an image says way more words than text. Could you share a screenshot of the prop?

Comment: @Enigmativity Added the picture of where I am now, tried using the button UI script with adding listeners and raycasting as is common with 3D objects, neither worked

Comment: @MaxPlay I added the picture of the prop, just the bulb on the bottom has the collider

Comment: What do you mean by "collider is pressed"?

Comment: If it's a sprite used normally for a 2D game normal Raycasts will work, if its a UI element you need to use the GraphicRaycaster, also you don't add colliders to UI elements

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. It's hard for us to refactor images.

Comment: Have you tried to simply use [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) instead?

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to add collider in ui spirte. create a transparent image on your golfclub head. then add component "Button" and add your method. its more simple to use.

Comment: Does this also work when I need to click and drag the club head? I assume buttons can have their position parented?